# Changing IIS application pool idenity from built in account to custom account causes 503 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, application-pool

I have an intranet web application developed using C# and .NET and it is hosted on our own internal webserver running IIS 8.5.

I have it set up the application pool to use the built in account `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and this works fine.

However I need the application to be able to browse a network drive so I have changed the application pool to use a custom account that has access to the network drive. I know it has access as I am using my login details here.

But when I browse to the website I get the following error

> **Service Unavailable**
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

When I recycle the application pool with these new settings I get the following error:

> There was an error while performing this operation Details The object
>   identifier does not represent a valid object. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800710D8)

I have also tried using the server admin account but I get the same error messages.

Thanks

**Edit**

The following message is in the event log

> The identity of application pool TestApplicationPool is invalid. The
>   user name or password that is specified for the identity may be
>   incorrect, or the user may not have batch logon rights. If the
>   identity is not corrected, the application pool will be disabled when
>   the application pool receives its first request.  If batch logon
>   rights are causing the problem, the identity in the IIS configuration
>   store must be changed after rights have been granted before Windows
>   Process Activation Service (WAS) can retry the logon. If the identity
>   remains invalid after the first request for the application pool is
>   processed, the application pool will be disabled. The data field
>   contains the error number.

Comment: Is it still broken if you change it back to ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Comment: Do these accounts have read/write access to the website directory? This also happens when the username/password is incorrect, are you entering the username in the correct format? domain\username

Comment: You could also try creating a new worker pool and assign this to the site to rule out any problems with the current one

Comment: @Polyfun changing it back to ApplicationPoolIdentity fixes the issue

Comment: @GJKH I have checked the permissions on the website directory and the user I have been entering has full permissions on this folder. I am definitely using the correct username/password as I am testing it with my own account. I am using the domain\username format.

Comment: @SimonTindall Have you tried creating a new application pool? Are there any useful errors in the event log?

Comment: @GJKH I have tried a new application pool and even written a single page web application and get the same errors. I checked the event log and found an event that may be of use which i have added to my original question

Comment: Did you try to follow the steps https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc515176(v=cs.70).aspx to add your pool account to IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: @LexLi yes I have added the pool account to IIS_IUSRS

Answer (score 0):

Try granting the user account permissions to access the required asp files and folders, from a command prompt

```
aspnet_regiis -ga "Domain\SomeAccount"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

**Also allow the account to logon as a service:**

Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a service

**Also add the account to the IIS_WPG Group**

In the Computer Management screen, under System Tools, expand Local Users and Groups, and then click Groups.

Right-click the IIS_WPG group, and then click Add to Group.

In the IIS_WPG Properties dialog box, click Add.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544832(v=cs.70).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt, i still receive the same error messages.

Comment: @SimonTindall see update on IIS_WPG group, apart from that the error would suggest that the username and or password has not been supplied correctly. Is this machine and user part of a domain? Does the user have read, read & execute & list folder contents permission on the website folder?

Comment: I dont have an option for IIS_WPG? The username and password are definitely correct...i use them to log on every day! I have checked the website folder and the the login ID has full read and write permissions. The machine and user are part of a domain and I am entering the details as such in the identity field domain\username.

Comment: You should have IIS_WPG group in local users and groups- >groups, it's part of IIS, I don't think it would work without it. http://pasteboard.co/yjUXDdMEi.png

Comment: This answer uses too old information. Notice IIS 7 and above no longer uses IIS_WPG group.

Comment: Yes i am using IIS 8.5

Answer (score 0):

The group is called `IIS_IUSRS` in newer versions of **IIS**.

You may also need the following:

- Access this computer from the network
- Adjust memory quotas for a process
- Allow log on locally
- Bypass traverse checking
- Generate security audit details
- Impersonate a client after authentication
- Log on as a batch job
- Log on as a service
- Replace a process level token

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to remove the custom account from the "Guests" group in Local Users and Groups